# How to get all of input date format in table by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create a html table with date input:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="start" type="date" value= ""/> ~ <input name="end" type="date" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="start" type="date" value= ""/> ~ <input name="end" type="date" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now I want to get all of input value to string by javascript like this:

```
2019-06-01~2019-06-02,2019-06-03~2019-06-04
```

I am just begin with javascript,can someone helps me? very thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the inputs as strings like this:

```js
function getDates() {
  var res = '';
  var rows = $('#myTable').find('tr');
  rows.each(function(index, el) {
    res += $(el).find('input[name=start]').val();
    res += '~';
    res += $(el).find('input[name=end]').val();
    if (index < rows.length - 1) {
      res += ', ';
    }
  });

  return res;
}

console.log(getDates());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="start" type="date" value="2018-01-23" /> ~ <input name="end" type="date" value="2019-01-22" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="start" type="date" value="2018-01-23" /> ~ <input name="end" type="date" value="2019-01-28" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and dates array will contain all dates input of your page

```
$('input[type="date"]').on('input',function(){
    let dates = [];
    $.each($('input[type="date"]'),function(){
        dates.push($this.val());
    }
}
```

and because thats an event you should put this in a

```
$(document).ready(function () {}
```